# Redirecting all traffic to a webpage to force http://www

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect, web-development-server

I have found several topics on forcing `https://` traffic to `http://` and maybe that is what I'm looking for, but since my specific instance is not mentioned and one would assume that all traffic is not https:// traffic I would not want to assume that it would redirect all traffic with these types of commands.

What I'm trying to find is a way to force all traffic that would attempt to visit `"testsite.com"`  to visit `"http://www.testsite.com"`.

As it stands if I type in `"www."` or `"http://www."` it will remove them from the address bar after the page loads and will only display `"testsite.com"`, and I know it's a ridiculous thing to nit pick at but its bothering me.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Are you using Chrome?  If so, Chrome doesn't *show* the `http://` part in the address bar, but it's still there.  Just try copy & pasting the url from the address bar to notepad, and the `http://` is there.

Comment: That's just the way modern browsers work these days, nothing you can do about it. The protocol is still there, it's just hidden by the browser.

Comment: Yea I guess it is there, kind of don't like that feature... lol
It's doing the same thing in edge, and firefox.
its even dropping the www. I find that very strange and undesireable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks David R. & APAD1 for the great responses.

Modern browsers just do that now, I suppose the majority of sites I visit anymore are `https://` so I just never noticed the change.

It's nice to know its all set up right and not something I can change.